# How to extend another modules declaration file?

Tags: typescript, adonis.js

I have an [AdonisJS](https://preview.adonisjs.com/) project, and have run into an issue regarding declaration files. Adonis' IoC container utilizes ES6 import [loader hooks](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/esm.html#esm_loader_hooks) in order to resolve dependencies. So for example, if I wanted to import my `User` model, it would look something like:

```js
import User from "@ioc:App/Models/User";
```

However, since Adonis uses the `@ioc:` prefix, webstorm doesn't know anything about the typings. To get around this, you can declare a typescript definition file in the `/contracts` directory which looks something like:

```js
declare module "@ioc:App/Models/User" {

}
```

But this still doesn't really help because now my `User` model doesn't have any typing information.

What I would like to do is *extend* the definition from the base `Model` class, `"@ioc:Adonis/Lucid/Model"`, for `"@ioc:App/Models/Users"`, with the option to add on any properties or methods that may be included in that model class. So far I tried something like this, but it doens't seem to do what I want:

```js
declare module "@ioc:App/Models/User" {
  import Model from "@ioc:Adonis/Lucid/Model";
  export default Model;
}
```

I am fairly new to typescript, so I apologize if this is fairly straightforward and I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

It seems my approach was correct, but I was using the wrong class provided by the framework, since models extend `BaseModel`, not `Model`. This is what I wanted:

```js
declare module "@ioc:App/Models/User" {
  import { BaseModel } from "@ioc:Adonis/Lucid/Orm";
  export default BaseModel;
}
```